Как получить у pipenv виртуальное окружение с определенным именем?
Всем привет. Как получить в pipenv виртуальное окружение с определенным именем? По дефолту данная утилита создает виртуальное окружение в директории $HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs с именем в виде "имя директории"+рандомные символы.
Хотя pipx в директории $HOME/.local/share/pipx/venvs делает виртуальные окружения с точным именем утилиты.

Что вы имеете в виду под словом «получить»?

Создать виртуальное окружение с определенным именем, а не рандомным, которое ему присваивает pipenv

PIPENV_CUSTOM_VENV_NAME https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#virtual-environment-name

Не очень способ, думал есть возможность задать глобально для всех будующих venvs

Тогда не очень понятно зачем

Не хочу иметь хеш в названии папок, в которых расположено виртуальное окружение, чтобы оно по дефолту называлось как папка с проектом

Во-первых, а какая разница, если вы всё равно не должны взаимодействовать с этими папками напрямую? Во-вторых, что pipenv должен делать, когда окажется несколько разных папок с одинаковым названием?

Пишу я bash скрипт для автоматизации настройки моего окружения. И есть набор python утилит, которыми я не хотел бы портить систему. И pipx на них выдает ошибку ERROR: git+https://github.com/... does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found. Но это прекрасно ставится ручками с помощью pipenv. Я бы хотел автоматизировать в скрипте клон данных утилит с GitHub, создание виртуального окружения под них и установку утилит в систему, но вот непонятно как делать если расположение виртуального окружения непонятно какое постоянно

Ну, bash-скрипт никак не мешает использовать хеши в названиях

"если расположение виртуального окружения непонятно какое" - вам не нужно его знать вообще, просто используйте pipenv для управления виртуальным окружением

Вроде такое сделал python_pipenv_dir=$(env PWD=$python_pipenv_project_dir pipenv --venv), не было понятно по какому алгоритму считается тот хеш
